# Type erasure with collections

Tags: java, generics

I am having trouble understanding how type erasure exactly works when collections are involved.

If we look at this code:

```
static void print(Object o){
   System.out.println("Object");
}
static void print(String s){
   System.out.println("String");
}
static void print(Integer i){
   System.out.println("Integer");
}
static <T> void printWithClass (T t)
   print(t);
}
public static void main(String[] args){
   printWithClass("abc") //String is printed, because T turns to Object after type erasure.
}
```

This example I understand, however this one I could not:

```
class Printer<T>{
    void print(Collection<?> c){
        System.out.println("1");
    }
    void print(List<Number> l){
        System.out.println("2");
    }
    void printWithClass(List<T> ts){
        print(ts);
    }
    
}

public class Main
{
 public static void main(String[] args){
        Printer<Integer> printer=new Printer<>();
        printer.printWithClass(new ArrayList< Integer>()); //1 is printed
    }  
}
```

I am unable to understand why exactly 1 is printed. It seemed to me that after type erasure the code will look like this:

```
        void print(Collection c){
            System.out.println("1");
        }
        void print(List l){
            System.out.println("2");
        }
        void printWithClass(List ts){
            print(ts);
        }
```

But this is wrong.

It seems to me as if there are two phases of type erasure - one that will turn T to Object, and then one where `List<...>` will be turned into `List`.

I don't think it's correct, can someone please explain what is happening here?

Edit: I came up with this guess: The compiler remembers that originally the parameter was `List<Number>` because it's important for separate compilation. However, it cannot remember that what came in originally to `printWithClass` was `List<Number>` as well, it can only know it was List<?>.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that method overloading is resolved at compile time (contrary to method *overriding* which will be resolved at runtime).

This means that the decision *which specific method signature* is being called will have to be done when `printWithClass` is compiled. Which also means that no type erasure is done at this point (since erasure is a property of the runtime, the compiler still cares about all the type parameters).

In this method:

```
void printWithClass(List<T> ts){
    print(ts);
}
```

with `T` being fully unbounded (i.e. it could be any reference type possible) there is only one possible `print` method to call, which is the one taking a `Collection<?>`, because we can't know that `T` is `Number`.

As a side-note, since a `List<Integer>` **is not** a `List<Number>`, even if these rules were different, your `main` method couldn't cause the other `print` method to be called.